# When i change file_get_contents to WP_Filesystem it doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme. It is almost complete. When i check it in theme-check plugin it give the warning

```
WARNING: file_get_contents was found in the file sources.php File operations
should use the WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls.
Line 84: $fonts = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/gwf.json');
```

Then i change `file_get_contents` to `WP_Filesystem` but it not getting the value or not working.

Here is the code of line 84:

```
function vp_get_gwf_family()
{
    $fonts = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/gwf.json');
    $fonts = json_decode($fonts);

    $fonts = array_keys(get_object_vars($fonts));

    foreach ($fonts as $font)
    {
        $result[] = array('value' => $font, 'label' => $font);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Share your new code that isn't working? Looking at [WP_filesystem](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) documentation, its a class not a function. So its not a simple replace. The API allows FTP based file changes if the server the code is working on is designed not to allow php to make file changes.

Comment: I read in a blog that says replace file_get_contents to WP_Filesystem
[Here](http://www.wrock.org/resolve-wordpress-theme-check-issue/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with wp_filesystem due to security settings on the server and ended up changing:

```
    global $wp_filesystem;
    $file   = $wp_filesystem->get_contents( get_template_directory() . '/assets/js/icomoon-selection.json' );
```

to:

```
    ob_start();
    include  dirname(__FILE__) .'/../assets/js/icomoon-selection.json';
    $file = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Maybe it solves your warnings (the example use of wp filesystem or the workaround).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I used these function to solve it.

```
public function icon_generator() {
  $file = THEMEOO_THEME_DIR . 'inc/icon/fa-icons.json';
  if ( is_readable( $file ) ) {
    $icons = WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents( $file ); // phpcs:ignore WordPressVIPMinimum.Performance.FetchingRemoteData.FileGetContentsUnknown
    if ( ! empty( $icons ) ) {
      $icons = json_decode( $icons );
      if ( isset( $icons->icons ) && ! empty( $icons->icons ) ) {
        foreach ( $icons->icons as $icon ) {
          echo '<a href="#" data-themeoo-icon="ti-' . esc_attr( $icon ) . '"><span class="ti-' . esc_attr( $icon ) . '"></a>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  die();
}
```

I think this will solve your problem. For better understanding you can [follow this tutorial](https://niamrox.com/file_get_contents-was-found-in-the-file-a-complete-solution-to-overcome-it/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get $wp_filesystem because you are not in the admin environment (e.g. if you are using REST API from wordpress, which is not an "admin" environment), then you can use php's native file_get_contents to replace $wp_filesystem->get_contents().
The param you need to pass into file_get_content() is the string that's after localhost:8080
e.g. for this local file:

```
http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/imagexyz.jpeg
```

You can acces it by:

```
$image_content = file_get_contents('wp-content/uploads/2021/11/imagexyz.jpeg');
```